# How can I slideToggle close other menus when current menu is open?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need some help with this navigation functionality.

When a user clicks on a Menu item  how can I close the other menus if they are open? Also, the `active` class needs to be disabled as well for the closed menus.

I have this navigation working how I want just except for this piece.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.navigationV1 ul.top-level-menu .label').on('click', function() {
    // Toggle top nav links
    $(this).siblings('.drop-down-menu').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #666;
}

.drop-down-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationV1 top-level-menu label">

  <div class="descendant-links-container">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 1</a>

        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Drop-down-menu 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 2</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Drop-down-menu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've formatted your code so it's a bit easier for us to see which are `siblings` - there was an `<a>` where it should have been `</a>` and a missing `</ul>` - it's unlikely these make a difference, assuming this is derived code for the question and not your real code - but worth checking your real code.

Comment: Without looking too closely, I would imagine you could do `$('.drop-down-menu').slideUp()` inside the click handler; similarly `$(".active").removeClass("active")`  likely with some limiting context such as only in the menu.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. that doesn't work. I just need the other menus to close and the active class to be disabled when a new menu is clicked on.

Comment: "*to close*" then `$('.drop-down-menu').close()`?   Not sure what "active class to be disabled" means - I assumed remove the active class, but taken literally it would be `$(".active").attr("disabled", "disabled")` which seems unlikely.

Comment: The answer below is working except when a user clicks on the same menu item twice that menu item closes and opens. That's basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `let thisMenu = $(this).siblings('.drop-down-menu');  $(".drop-down-menu").not(thisMenu).close();  thisMenu.slideDown()`  - use slideDown if you want to *force* it to be open (which it sounds like you do) and toggle if you want to ... well... toggle it.

Comment: That snippet of code isn't working. It's breaking what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to find all open menus and close them and next open the new menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.navigationV1 ul.top-level-menu .label').on('click', function() {
        // Close already opened menus
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.label.active').removeClass('active').siblings('.drop-down-menu').slideUp();
        }
        // Toggle top nav links
        $(this).siblings('.drop-down-menu').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: Hello my friend! So that's working only issue is when you click on the same menu item twice that menu item closes and opens. How can we fix that?

Comment: Hi, I fixed this and edited the code above